# Regarding removal of Activity Title bar in Android

Tags: android, coding-style, android-sdk-2.1, android-titlebar, android-theme

i have already set the theme of my activity as android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
but i also want to remove the title bar of the activity. so how to use 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
along with the dialog theme.

Comment: `Theme.Dialog` creates a floating transparent widget where you can see underlying activities. Are you sure that the titlebar does not belong to an underlying activity

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try creating a custom style that extends `Theme.Dialog`:

```
<resources>
    <style name="DialogNoTitle" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: this is the CORRECT and greatest answer!!!  I wish the OP would accept this answer.  saved me so much time.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can specify this in your activity's onCreate():

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: yeah but you need to do no.theme in the activity tag in the manifest otherwise you still will have a title flash at application startup

Answer (score 0):

For `AppCompat`, following solution worked for me:

Add new theme style with no action bar in your `styles.xml` and set `parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"`.

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>
```

Now implement the same theme style to your splash screen activity in `androidManifest.xml`

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityName"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"> // apply splash them here 

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is result:

[image]