# Android to setaction bar without title bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to set action bar without title bar.

I have tried `@android:style/theme.light.notitlebar` 
as well as i also tried this link [Adding an action bar to Theme.Black.NoTitleBar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379916/adding-an-action-bar-to-theme-black-notitlebar-android)

but it is not working . Where i am wrong, please help me

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme

Answer (score 0):

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Comment: but i also need to remain action bar while doing this iotherwise  it will show null pointer exception

Comment: Try this link might help [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4171742/regarding-removal-of-activity-title-bar-in-android)